# Chrome Extension error tab.url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm essentially just trying to get the current tab url if they're on youtube.com. I keep getting an error from the script.

> `Error:`
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSelected' of undefined`

Manifest

```
{
    "name": "YouTube Fix",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Fix some of the annoying little things in YouTube.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["background.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

Background.js

```
//this is what is giving me the error:
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    myFunction(tab.url);
});

function myFunction(tablink) {
    if (tablink == "http://www.youtube.com") {
        window.location = "http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/u";
    }
    document.getElementById("comments-textarea").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following forks fine, no need for `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {})`,because your page always runs for `"matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],`;

More over add this condition to your code `if(document.getElementById("comments-textarea") != null){`

**Working background.js**

```
 if (window.location == "http://www.youtube.com") {
        window.location = "http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions/u";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("comments-textarea") != null) {
        document.getElementById("comments-textarea").disabled = false;
    }
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "YouTube Fix",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Fix some of the annoying little things in YouTube.",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["background.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This is probably closer to useful than my answer. Note that the original code runs on `http://www.youtube.com/*` but tests exactly `http://www.youtube.com/` (i.e., the home page), so they probably still need the first `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You're running background.js as a content script rather than a background or event page, and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html says that "content scripts have some limitations. They cannot … Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)"

Instead, you should put something like

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

into your manifest. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from here:  https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/A5bMuwCfBkQ

> chrome.tabs.getSelected() is deprecated.  The following page explains
>   how to use chrome.tabs.query instead:
>   http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#16 The relevant bit of text is: 
>   """
>   The methods getAllInWindow() and getSelected() have been deprecated.
>   To get details about all tabs in the specified window, use
>   chrome.tabs.query() with the argument {'windowId': windowID}. To get
>   the tab that is selected in the specified window, use
>   chrome.tabs.query() with the argument {'active': true}.
>   """

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` is [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16). Use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "active": true
}, function(tab){
    console.log(tab[0]);  //selected tab
});
```

Also, content scripts [can not access](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) `chrome.tabs` APIs. Do this:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.query(...
```

(This might not work. Not tested.)

Comment: Being deprecated doesn't mean it's removed. "chrome.tabs.getSelected" works just fine from a test background page. Also, if the problem were that getSelected had been removed, the error would have been "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getSelected'".

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin - I'm sorry, but where in the answer say it does not work anymore?

Comment: Saying that getSelected is deprecated is irrelevant to the question in that fixing that problem wouldn't get the author any closer to having a working extension. It's certainly true and useful to comment on, but it's not an answer.